# inorder traversal pointing to wrong array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tree, tree-traversal

I am writing a simple function for `inorder traversal` of a tree. The function looks like  this:

```
 /**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * function TreeNode(val, left, right) {
 *     this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
 *     this.left = (left===undefined ? null : left)
 *     this.right = (right===undefined ? null : right)
 * }
 */
/**
 * @param {TreeNode} root
 * @return {number[]}
 */
var inorderTraversal = function(root,typ, par) {
    
    let  result = [] ;
     console.log(`side = ${typ} currentVal = ${root? root.val: 'no root'}`,root)
     if (!root) return  []
     left =  inorderTraversal(root.left, 'left', root.val)
     right = inorderTraversal(root.right, 'right', root.val )
     console.log(`side = ${typ} currentVal = ${root? root.val: 'no root'}  parent = ${par}`,root)
     console.log(`${root.val}-left, and parent= ${par}`, left)
     console.log(`${root.val}-rigth, and parent= ${par}`, right)
     result = [...left, root.val, ...right ];
     console.log('res', result)
     return result
     
    
    
};
```

Note: The `brnch`(represents the side I am traversing i.e left/right) and  `par`(parent's value), are just parameters I pass for debugging purposes.

The  problem or challenge I am working on can be  found  here: https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-inorder-traversal/submissions/

The function recursively traverses through a tree and when the left and right sides are determined, it uses the spread operator to combine them.

My console.logs output are:

```
side = undefined currentVal = 1 [1,null,2,3]
side = left currentVal = no root null
side = right currentVal = 2 [2,3]
side = left currentVal = 3 [3]
side = left currentVal = no root null
side = right currentVal = no root null
side = left currentVal = 3  parent = 2 [3]
3-left, and parent= 2 []
3-rigth, and parent= 2 []
res [ 3 ]
side = right currentVal = no root null
side = right currentVal = 2  parent = 1 [2,3]
2-left, and parent= 1 [ 3 ]
2-rigth, and parent= 1 []
res [ 3, 2 ]
side = undefined currentVal = 1  parent = undefined [1,null,2,3]
1-left, and parent= undefined [ 3 ]
1-rigth, and parent= undefined [ 3, 2 ]
res [ 3, 1, 3, 2 ]
```

my input is `[1,null,2,3]`. the expected output is `[1,3,2]` and  the current/actual result  is `[3,1,3,2]`

If you look at the logs(specifically the last 3 lines), you'll see when the function bubbles back up to when root val is 1, the left is [3], right is `[3,2]`. If the left wasn't [3] then I would get the correct result with [left, root.val, right]. Can someone explain why is left returning `[3]`? I think it should be `[]`. In a similar sub-problem where root.val is 2 and the right leaf is null, I get right = `[]`. I don't know why left is `[3]`.

I don't need a solution for inorder traversal but rather answer to why left is returning `[3]`. In addition, when I change the order of when operations are performed, the  problem is resolved. code :

```
var inorderTraversal = function(root,typ, par) {
    
    let  result = [] ;
     console.log(`side = ${typ} currentVal = ${root? root.val: 'no root'}`,root)
     if (!root) return  []
     left =  inorderTraversal(root.left, 'left', root.val)
     //modifying result before traversing right
     result = [...left, root.val]
     right = inorderTraversal(root.right, 'right', root.val )
     console.log(`side = ${typ} currentVal = ${root? root.val: 'no root'}  parent = ${par}`,root)
     console.log(`${root.val}-left, and parent= ${par}`, left)
     console.log(`${root.val}-rigth, and parent= ${par}`, right)
     result = [...result, ...right ];
     console.log('res', result)
     return result
     
    
    
};
```

This resolves the issue even though the left is still `[3]`, can someone please help with why this happens?

Comment: try declaring `left` et al as local: `let left`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scope is interfering with the value that you get, try restricting the scope of `left` and `right` variables to local using `let`.

```
var inorderTraversal = function(root) {
    
    let  result = [] ;
     if (!root) return  []
     let left =  inorderTraversal(root.left, 'left', root.val)
     let right = inorderTraversal(root.right, 'right', root.val )
     result = [...left, root.val , ...right ];
     return result
     
    
    
};
```